# How can I get web app-generated data (javascript) to my user given browser security blocks?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, dropbox

I'm building an audio web app, an old-style amiga mod tracker, on github at https://github.com/jscuster/webtracker/ . I want the user to save the end result. 
I understand browsers today don't offer functionality to do this. I have investigated using a data uri, but this doesn't let my app specify a file extension, very important. I experimented with the "download" attribute, but it seems hit-and-miss.

I looked at the saver drop-in script for dropbox, I've tried using url shorteners, and several other ideas, but they all seem to require me to upload the user's files to my server, then give a url to the file. I have seen that flash-based tools are available, but I'd like this web app to be useable on iPhone and android, which don't handle flash content.

As it seems impossible for me to allow users to just save the blasted file on their hdd, I'd like to enable users to save the file in the cloud, maybe dropbox or google drive, without going through my server. Can this be done? Are there any other suggestions to get the file to its creator?

Comment: I found jszip, http://stuk.github.io/jszip/ which allows my app to preserve its file and extension info in a zip file, but the problem exists as the user still has to rename the zip file to [anyName].zip in most browsers if I use a data url. The problem still exists, but is a little bit better with this method. Still hoping for an answer, it must not be possible though, 19 views in 4 days and no answer yet.